# Is Bitcode required for iPadOS apps?

Tags: bitcode, ipados

[Apple documentation](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devbbdc5ce4f) does not mention whether or not bitcode is required for iPadOS apps:

> For iOS apps, bitcode is the default, but optional. For watchOS and tvOS apps, bitcode is required. If you provide bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle (all targets in the project) need to include bitcode

If some one found a valid source of information regarding this question, please share.